# Entity Framework not inserting new entity into database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm trying to insert a particular entity into the db by doing:

```
var myItem = new Item() { // properties here...};

myContext.Entry(myItem).State = EntityState.Added;
myContext.SaveChanges();
```

However, EF (v6.2) is not even sending the insert SQL statement to the Db.

For all other entities, inserting works fine. I'm also not using auto detect changes.

Is there a way to debug why EF is not creating the SQL statement ie. why it's not recognizing the new entity as `new`?

Comment: There is no DbEntityValidationException exception thrown?

Comment: @WillyDavidJr Nothing. No exception. `SaveChanges` returns 0 (ie. no entities added)

Comment: which EF version - and you need to give some 'context' to all this, i.e. create a [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: We need to see the class and the mapping code (if any). This doesn't give any clue. Also, what do you mean by "I'm also not using auto detect changes". Do you disable it? If so, why?

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
var myItem = new Item() { // properties here...};

myContext.Entry(myItem).State = EntityState.Added;
myContext.SaveChanges();
```

To:

```
var myItem = new Item() { // properties here...};

myContext.TableName.Add(myItem);
myContext.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be related to improper disposal of your context. Make sure your context is always disposed of immediately after use like so:

```
using(var myContext = new MyContext())
{
   var myItem = new Item() { // properties here...};

   myContext.Entry(myItem).State = EntityState.Added;
   myContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: It's another way to doing it. Check this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592676(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: I'm wondering if your logic needs to be wrapped in a "using" block for your context. Maybe the context is meant to be disposed of immediately after? I'm not sure.

Comment: Actually, yes. If it isn't wrapped in a using block that could be your problem. Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17544897/insert-into-database-using-context-doesnt-work

Comment: EF isn't even generating the SQl script for the insert on `SaveChanges`. This particular model is not working as expected. All other models work fine and yes, I'm using `using` in my Unit of Work pattern.

Comment: Well, with what you've given there's no way to know what the issue is. It could be a problem with the context code itself. Try deleting the model and having EF regenerate.

Comment: Context disposal has nothing to do with this. `SaveChanges()` is not waiting for its context to be disposed before it actually does anything.